# Using Jackson to parse JSON and extract embedded type

Tags: java, json, jackson

Say I have a compound JSON object like so:

```
{
   "Person": {
               "name":"test",
               "age": 20
             },
   "Animal": {
               "name":"Max"
             }
}
```

This JSON representation has two embedded types `Person` and `Animal`, yet, I want to parse and extract a representation of each individual type (resulting in two Strings?).

Is this possible? I was thinking of using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) but can't find a suitable example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any JSON parser can do this.

If you're not looking to map to a POJO and want to use Jackson, you're probably looking for the Tree Model: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel

Comment: Using Jackson with the TreeModel was the solution in the end. I couldn't find a suitable example showing how to extract the individual types from the JSON; the end solution can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/1220791).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exact details, but if you just mean that you have 2 different properties, with different types, you could have classes like:

```
public class Response {
  public Person Person;
  public Animal Animal;
}
public class Person {
  public String name;
  public int age;
}
public class Animal {
  public String name;
}
```

(and/or use setters, getters).

But if you are looking for polymorphic types (types Person and animal being related), it requires more work.